# Amazon EMR use spot instances as core and Master Nodes using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I want to use spot instances for EMR using terraform. I'm able to do it using CLI:

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.3.1 --service-role 
EMR_DefaultRole \
--ec2-attributes InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole \
--instance-fleets 
InstanceFleetType=MASTER,TargetSpotCapacity=1,InstanceTypeConfigs= . 
['{InstanceType=m4.large,BidPrice=0.5}'] \
InstanceFleetType=CORE,TargetSpotCapacity=1,InstanceTypeConfigs= . 
['{InstanceType=m4.large,BidPrice=0.5}']`
```

But I can't find instance-fleets functionality in terraform. How could I accomplish the same using terraform

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a bid price for the instances your EMR cluster uses under the [`instance_group` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#instance_group-1) to have Terraform use spot instances for the instances.

The [example in the `aws_emr_cluster` resource documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#example-usage) shows how this should be specified:

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr-test-cluster" {
  name          = "emr-test-arn"
  release_label = "emr-4.6.0"
  applications  = ["Spark"]
  additional_info = <<EOF
{
  "instanceAwsClientConfiguration": {
    "proxyPort": 8099,
    "proxyHost": "myproxy.example.com"
  }
}
EOF

  termination_protection = false
  keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps = true

  ec2_attributes {
    subnet_id                         = "${aws_subnet.main.id}"
    emr_managed_master_security_group = "${aws_security_group.sg.id}"
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = "${aws_security_group.sg.id}"
    instance_profile                  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.emr_profile.arn}"
  }

  instance_group {
      instance_role = "CORE"
      instance_type = "c4.large"
      instance_count = "1"
      ebs_config {
        size = "40"
        type = "gp2"
        volumes_per_instance = 1
      }
      bid_price = "0.30"
      autoscaling_policy = <<EOF
{
"Constraints": {
  "MinCapacity": 1,
  "MaxCapacity": 2
},
"Rules": [
  {
    "Name": "ScaleOutMemoryPercentage",
    "Description": "Scale out if YARNMemoryAvailablePercentage is less than 15",
    "Action": {
      "SimpleScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
        "AdjustmentType": "CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY",
        "ScalingAdjustment": 1,
        "CoolDown": 300
      }
    },
    "Trigger": {
      "CloudWatchAlarmDefinition": {
        "ComparisonOperator": "LESS_THAN",
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "MetricName": "YARNMemoryAvailablePercentage",
        "Namespace": "AWS/ElasticMapReduce",
        "Period": 300,
        "Statistic": "AVERAGE",
        "Threshold": 15.0,
        "Unit": "PERCENT"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
EOF
}
  ebs_root_volume_size     = 100

  master_instance_type = "m3.xlarge"
  core_instance_type   = "m3.xlarge"
  core_instance_count  = 1

  tags {
    role     = "rolename"
    env      = "env"
  }

  bootstrap_action {
    path = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if"
    name = "runif"
    args = ["instance.isMaster=true", "echo running on master node"]
  }

  configurations_json = <<EOF
  [
    {
      "Classification": "hadoop-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Properties": {}
    },
    {
      "Classification": "spark-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Properties": {}
    }
  ]
EOF  

  service_role = "${aws_iam_role.iam_emr_service_role.arn}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, however in the documentation of EMR module it mentions the bid price. The new AWS Spot market doesn't require to set prices of instances, also I want both master and core nodes be spot. However Terraform documentation mentions: `bid_price can not be set for the MASTER instance group, since that group must always be On-Demand`

Comment: So just set the bid price to be the same as the on demand price for the same behaviour? Also the documentation is simply outdated if the AWS API now allows you to add spot MASTER instances to your EMR cluster because there isn't currently a check in the Terraform code to prevent that from happening.